# Run ldd for a binary with parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, shared-libraries, ldd

I know `ldd` can only take a binary as its parameter what I am asking here is how to run `ldd` with a binary, say, `mybin`, with parameter of the binary. For instance, `mybin --myparam ./configfile.conf`.

The linker will differ if I add the conf file for my binary because it loads some plugins in runtime with the plugins' shared object files, `plugin1.so` something like this. I have some undefined reference issue but I still got no idea which `.so` file I was missing.

If I run `ldd ./mybin`, everything is linked and running the plain binary is fine. Once I add the conf file for my binary, to let it loads some plugins shared library, then my binary will report errors when loading those library(coded exception throw, with some `undefined reference` error messages).

So if there is way to run `ldd` with `mybin --myparam ./a.file` something like this would help a lot.

Comment: Try stracing to find the problematic libraries and then run `ldd` on that library?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh yeah, your comment is also useful because I actually have the shared library path which can run `ldd` against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable for this. To see the relevant options, run any command with `LD_DEBUG=help`. For example, running `LD_DEBUG=help ls` on my machine gives this output:

```
LD_DEBUG=help ls
Valid options for the LD_DEBUG environment variable are:

  libs        display library search paths
  reloc       display relocation processing
  files       display progress for input file
  symbols     display symbol table processing
  bindings    display information about symbol binding
  versions    display version dependencies
  scopes      display scope information
  all         all previous options combined
  statistics  display relocation statistics
  unused      determined unused DSOs
  help        display this help message and exit

To direct the debugging output into a file instead of standard output
a filename can be specified using the LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT environment variable.
```

One way of debugging your `dlopen`s, or whatever late loading mechanism you are using, would be to run your executables with the relevant args with `LD_DEBUG=all`. This would give you a lengthy output detailing symbol lookups and search paths. This output would also tell you about resolution failures.